# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Issue

Tags: asp.net, .net-1.1

I have inherited a webforms application that was working and now is not.

The error text is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
".

Im sorry it is sooo generic, but I was wondering if anyone could read the Stack Trace and point me in right direction?

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
GAP07.Index_UK.LoadData() +2060
GAP07.Index_UK.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +5
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +67
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain() +750
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2443; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2470

Thanks Paul

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You might start by turning on `<compilation debug="true">` and deploying the pdbs in order to get actual line numbers. However, @moose has you in the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: VS Debugger ... *attach process* :) Also, use a *scm tool* so that it's easier to find "what made it break".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably reading data in LoadData(), and that is returning null for an object.. Then you are trying to access a member or property of that object.  Hard to tell more from the stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, he is loading an object that is returning null and then trying to access one of it's members.  Best way to debug is to step through it.